# Three.js: point light strange spot on the ground

Tags: three.js, aframe

[Example here](https://codepen.io/Disorrder/pen/jBzExv)

I'm using PointLight in scene and ground reflects big light spot. What should I do to remove it? I only need to highlight some area on scene. So, I can decrease `distance` but it only decreasing size of spot. Not exactly I've expected. Should I use specific material on the ground or something like this?

[image: light spot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is very easy: set ground material's `roughness` to 1. I've updated example to see how roughness changes material.